# PHP HTTP response code 404

Tags: php

On my website, I am using dynamic URLs of the form below

http://example.php/productdetail.php?mobileproductid=17645

When the product id is greater than the max existing in DB, I want to issue an HTTP 404 response code and want to load a 404.php file. This is the current architecture of page

1. Load the Headers ( part of the header files)
2. In the productdetail.php file, I perform the check below:

```
$mobileproductid = $_REQUEST['mobileproductid'];
$return = mobile::mobiledetail($con,$mobileproductid);
if(mysqli_num_rows($return)=='0')
{
    http_response_code(404);
}
else{
    /* Load the page */
}
```

When I check the response code for any invalid id, it is 200. What am I missing ?

PHP version : 5.4.42

Comment: What does mysqli_num_rows($return) return? Do `echo mysqli_num_rows($return) `

Comment: It is returning a zero. Thats why the rest of the page is not loading as the else condition never runs.

Comment: perhaps your framework (if any) is resetting the status header. Try `var_dump(headers_list());` at the end of your script and see if your `404` is replaced by a `200`. Also you could use: `header("HTTP/1.0 418 I'm A Teapot");`

Comment: I got the issue. I am loading the header and then performing the check. If I perform the check before the header load, it is working. Thanks

Comment: You are sending http response code after response is created. So that's a waste!

Comment: Thats what I realized !

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed. Please consider posting the solution as an answer instead of a comment, so everyone can see it! Also, PHP 5.4 is obsolete - it doesn't even get security updates anymore! You really should upgrade to 5.6 or 7.0.